# ArgumentError in ActiveAdmin::Devise::Passwords#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i m trying in admin forgot password functionality , but its giving argument error, i have seen routes are perfect ,and in all environments config.action_mailer.default_url_options url is perfect.

but i still cant fixx the issue, can u give me some advice what other things i can try

Showing where line #5 raised:

Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true

```
      unless host
        raise ArgumentError, "Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true"
      end

      build_host_url(host, port, protocol, options, path_for(options))
```

i tried changing code for forgot password, routes were already okk,tried checking .env still cant find the issue

Comment: `config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }` and `config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://localhost:3000"` should work ?